# emacs - open multiple files at once in tabs?

Tags: emacs

I'm using tabbed mode but it doesn't seem to (or I don't know how to) open different files in different tabs. Could anyone tell me of a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you referring to tabbar-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open multiple files at once with filename globbing, just as you would use in your shell.

e.g.: <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> `*.txt` <kbd>RET</kbd> to open all text files in the current directory.

I don't use any kind of tab library (and Emacs does not offer tabs by default, so I'll echo 0x4b's query about where your tabs are coming from?), but if it displays each buffer in a different tab, then this may be enough to do what you want.

Comment: Does this work with ido-mode? When I entered `*.txt` for example, Emacs opened a file *called* `*.txt`.